# LWC @api boolean attribute issue

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass value to a public boolean property in a web component from a parent lwc. 
Child JS definition:

```
  export default class GsdDseUserProfilePicture extends LightningElement {
     @api userRecordId;
     @api circular = false;
     @api readonly = false;
```

Parent html:

```
<c-gsd-dse-user-profile-picture user-record-id={userRecord.id} width="150px" height="150px" circular readonly>
```

But when I am printing the value in console in a function:

```
    get showCameraIcon() {
      var showIcon = false;
      console.log("TCL: getshowCameraIcon -> showIcon", showIcon);
      console.log("TCL: getshowCameraIcon -> this.readOnly", this.readonly);
      if (this.readonly === false) {
       showIcon = true;
      }
      console.log("TCL: getshowCameraIcon -> showIcon", showIcon);
      return showIcon;   
}
```

I always get `false` in logs for `this.readonly` property. Weird part is that I get the correct value of `circular` property. Since, these are @api marked properies, so there is no chance that these values can change later on in child component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those weird bugs found in Salesforce!.

I just tried changing it to `readOnly` and used `read-only` in HTML, Also used `readonlyicon`. In short any other variable except `readonly` seems to work!

---

I am getting below error when using `readonly`:

[image]

And in fact there is no `readOnly` anywhere. I guess LWC is internally using readonly.

**------ ADDED ----------**

This is actually not a bug. `readonly` is global HTML attribute. Same is the case with other global attributes like `bgcolor`, `colspan`, `datetime` etc. So, we should be using camel casing for them as documented in LWC. [This is the reference.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/js_props_names)

Comment: Yeah. Got it working with `readOnly`. Thanks.

Comment: `readOnly` camelcase no longer works for me, though instead of always returning false returns undefined. I ended up using `@api fromReadOnly` to be extra different, and attribute is passing properly now.